# Java - Get Single XML Value

Tags: java, xml

I have searched and found many possible solutions, but I have not gotten any of them to work. I need to pull down an XML and save it to disc and then recall it and pull an elements value from it. I have successfully saved the XML to disc, but now I can't get the value from the single element. I found a bunch of loops and arrays to get all the data in different forums but I seem to be failing.

Any help would be appreciated, and I know I have a bunch of extra and repeating imports, it is just mess from trying so many things. Thanks!!!

The XML:

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
<licenseActivated>
  <licenseKey>654</licenseKey>
  <expirationDate>10/31/2016</expirationDate>
  <uniqueId>Unique ID</uniqueId>
</licenseActivated>
```

```js
//
//  Sample License App for COMP394
//

// Import statements
import java.util.Scanner; 
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.DataOutputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.io.*;
import java.net.HttpURLConnection;
import java.net.URL;
import javax.net.ssl.HttpsURLConnection;
import javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilder;
import javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilderFactory;
import java.net.URLConnection;
import java.io.InputStream;
import org.w3c.dom.Document;
import org.w3c.dom.NodeList;
import org.w3c.dom.Element;
import org.w3c.dom.NodeList;
import org.w3c.dom.Node;
import org.w3c.dom.Document;
import org.w3c.dom.NamedNodeMap;
import javax.xml.xpath.*;
import org.xml.sax.InputSource;
import javax.xml.transform.*;
import javax.xml.transform.stream.StreamResult;
import javax.xml.transform.dom.DOMSource;
import javax.xml.xpath.XPath;
import javax.xml.xpath.XPathFactory;
import javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilderFactory;
import javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilder;
import org.xml.sax.SAXException;
import org.xml.sax.SAXParseException; 
import javax.xml.xpath.XPath;
import javax.xml.xpath.XPathConstants;
import javax.xml.xpath.XPathFactory;





class LicenseApp {
 
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        LicenseApp http = new LicenseApp();

  System.out.println("Key Verifyication!!!");
  
  http.sendkey();
  //while( http.validation2() == false)
  //{
   //System.out.println("Key is wrong");
  //}
  
  //System.out.println("Confgrats, the key is good!!! \nContinue with your program!!!");

    }
 

 private boolean sendkey() {
  
  Scanner user_input = new Scanner(System.in);
  String key;
  System.out.println("Please enter your key."); // Outputs the prompt for information
  key = user_input.next( );
  boolean valid = false;
  
  DocumentBuilderFactory domFactory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
  
  try
  {
   
   String urlString = "http://localhost/license_response.php?response=activate&license=" + key;
   URL url = new URL(urlString);
   URLConnection conn = url.openConnection();

   DocumentBuilderFactory factory2 = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
   DocumentBuilder builder = factory2.newDocumentBuilder();
   Document doc = builder.parse(conn.getInputStream());
//   doc.getDocumentElement().normalize();

   TransformerFactory factory3 = TransformerFactory.newInstance();
   Transformer xform = factory3.newTransformer();

   //xform.transform(new DOMSource(doc), new StreamResult(System.out)); // Outputs to screen
   DOMSource source = new DOMSource(doc);
   StreamResult output = new StreamResult(new File("C:\\school\\COMP394\\Project\\Java.Program\\license.xml"));
   xform.transform(source, output); // Saves to file



   

  }
  
  catch(Exception e)
  {
   
  }
  
  return valid; // Return boolean value

  
 }
 

}
```

Comment: Do you mean "file", not "disc"?

Answer (score 1):

Thanks but I finally found it.

String ID = doc.getElementsByTagName("uniqueId").item(0).getTextContent();